How to format a monster table in latex
Here is a table I am attempting to format to put in my thesis. It is supposed to have 60 elements however I am starting with the first 5. I am having an enormous amount of trouble finding ways to get all 13 columns to fit on one page landscape with proper centering and text-wrapping.
The current format of the thesis margins are why they are so far from the edge and is a requirement.
Columns 1-3 I have as "c" so that the table wraps them as small as possible
Columns 4-6 are the desired length to accommodate names
Column  7 is the same as 1-3
Column 8 is set to expand to make the table expand to the width of the page
Column 9-12 are desired length to accommodate certain names
Column 13 is set to expand to contents like #8
This table is a monster and I would like to incorporate all of this information however I am having an extremely difficult time with what I have built so far.
Pararbox is used instead of makecell in column 8 because I could not find a way to center contents vertically while also allow wrapping with commas. If I use 2 arguments with parabox the whole table uncenters.
Here is what the margins should be:
Left margin: 1 inch + 21pt
Right margin: 109pt
Top margin: 1 inch + 9pt
Bottom margin: 161pt
And for clarification on the errors the only errors that arise are from the parabox output. I have tested this and leaving the parabox inputs blank allows the correct spacing in that column. Without the parabox there are only warnings about the contents taking up to much space.
\documentclass[10pt,american]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % Centered column
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % Left-aligned, vertically centered
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}        % Left-aligned, vertically centered X column

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}                         % Adjusted spacing
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}                  % Redefine X columns to be vertically centered

\begin{landscape}
\begin{footnotesize}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|
    c|        % Column 1
    c|        % Column 2
    c|        % Column 3
    C{18mm}|  % Column 4
    L{5em}|   % Column 5
    L{1cm}|   % Column 6
    c|        % Column 7
    Y|        % Column 8
    L{3cm}| % Column 9
    L{5em}|   % Column 10
    L{5em}|   % Column 11
    L{8em}|   % Column 12
    Y|        % Column 13
}
\hline
% Header row
\# &        % Column 1
Ref. &      % Column 2
Year &      % Column 3
Model &     % Column 4
Frameworks &% Column 5
Fusion &    % Column 6
Mod. &      % Column 7
Features &  % Column 8
Dataset &   % Column 9
Samples &   % Column 10
No. of Classes & % Column 11
Task &      % Column 12
Performance \\ % Column 13
\hline

% Entry 1
1 & \cite{PARK2016} & 2016 & Sentiment Classification \& Regression &
\makecell[l]{SVM \\ SVR} & Feature Fusion & \makecell{T \\ V \\ A} &
\parbox{\raggedright
    T: Unigrams, Bigrams \\
    V: Emotions, FAV, Eye Gaze, Movement Displacements \\
    A: MFCC, Pitch, VA (velocity)
} &
Persuasive Opinion Multimedia (POM) & 1,000 movie reviews & 2 (positive,\allowbreak{} negative) & Prediction of persuasiveness in movie reviews &
\makecell[l]{Acc: 70.34\% \\ PCC/Or: 0.34} \\
\hline

% Entry 2
2 & \cite{} & 2015 & Multi CNN & CNN & Feature Fusion & \makecell{T \\ V} &
\parbox{\raggedright
    T: Word vectors \\
    V: Images
} &
\makecell[l]{Twitter Dataset 1 (TD1) \\ Twitter Dataset 2 (TD2)} &
\makecell[l]{603 tweets \\ 1,369 tweets} &
2 (positive,\allowbreak{} negative) &
Multimodal Sentiment Analysis &
\makecell[l]{TD1 (Acc): 78\% \\ TD2 (Acc): 79.6\%} \\
\hline

% Entry 3
3 & \cite{} & 2020 & Multi-Attention Recurrent Neural Network (MA-RNN) & BiGRU & Feature Fusion & \makecell{T \\ V \\ A} &
\parbox{\raggedright
    T: Word2vec vectors \\
    V: feature maps, \# of channels, \# of frames, frame height x width \\
    A: MFCC, pitch, voice intensity, statistics e.g. $\bar{x}$
} &
CMU-MOSI & 2,199 video segments & 2 (positive,\allowbreak{} negative) &
Multimodal Sentiment Analysis & Acc: 84.31\% \\
\hline

% Entry 4
4 & \cite{} & 2021 & Contextual Multimodal Fusion with Attention Model & BiLSTM & \makecell[l]{Feature Fusion \\ Hierarchical Fusion} & \makecell{T \\ V \\ A} &
\parbox{\raggedright
    T: Word vectors \\
    V: 3D-CNN features \\
    A: MFCC, pitch, voice intensity, statistics e.g. $\bar{x}$
} &
\makecell[l]{IEMOCAP \\ CMU-MOSI} & \makecell[l]{5,498 utterances \\ 2,199 video segments} &
\makecell[l]{4 (happiness, sadness, anger, neutral) \\ 2 (positive, negative)} &
Multimodal Sentiment Analysis & \makecell[l]{IEMOCAP (Acc): 80.38\% \\ CMU-MOSI (Acc): 80.18\%} \\
\hline

% Entry 5
5 & \cite{} & 2024 & Text-Centric Multimodal Contrastive Learning (TCMCL) & Siamese NN & Feature Fusion & \makecell{T \\ V \\ A} &
\parbox{\raggedright
    T: BERT embeddings \\
    V: FACET library \\
    A: COVAREP toolkit
} &
\makecell[l]{CMU-MOSI \\ CMU-MOSEI} & \makecell[l]{2,199 video segments \\ 23,452 video segments} &
\makecell[l]{7 (strongly positive to strongly negative) \\ 7 (strongly positive to strongly negative)} &
Multimodal Sentiment Analysis & \makecell[l]{CMU-MOSI (Acc2): 86.7\% \\ CMU-MOSEI (Acc2): 85.8\%} \\
\hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{landscape}




Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ, what the main document font and font size are (if they're not the resp. defaults), and how wide the margins are. Please confirm that, at a minimum, one needs to load the array, tabularx, pdflscape, and makecell packages. Incidentally, \parbox takes 2 arguments, not one -- please fix.

BTW, why you load adjustbox three times? It is sufficient  and is strongly recommended to load it just one times ...

Thanks for providing some additional information. Some additional questions: What's the paper size: A4? US letter? something else? How wide are the margins?

The manual of the package pdflscape says in section "1.4 Usage": "Load this package instead of or after package lscape" while your preamble loads pdflscape before lscape.

we really need to be able to reproduce the output you show since you want help with something really very specific. also, do you not get errors with this code? if so, the output is essentially irrelevant as it is not reliable and you need to address the errors first.

If the Features always correspond to the Mod., if might make sense to not repeat the Mod. letters but instead have them line up by putting them in the same row.  That would require all other entries being \multirow, however.

Or maybe delete column 7, since it's information is repeated in column 8.

Something like this?

Note that you can save a lot of scarce horizontal space by omitting the 14 [!] vertical rules and suppressing the whitespace padding at both edges of the table. I further suggest calculating many of the column widths on the fly via \widthof statements, choosing the widths based on what "makes sense" visually. With this setup, there's no need for \parbox or \makecell directives. I don't see any advantage in using m- instead of p-type columns.
\documentclass[10pt,american]{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \fi
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{babel,pdflscape,ragged2e,calc,booktabs}

% 'xltabular' combines the capabilities of 'longtable' and 'tabularx':
\usepackage{xltabular} 
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\nobreakdash' macro

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\providecommand{\TV}{T \newline V}   % handy shortcut macros
\providecommand{\TVA}{\TV \newline A}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\footnotesize % \footnotesize is a switch, not an environment
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % default: 6pt

%\vspace*{3in} % for the second screenshot (see the addendum below)

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}
    l                              % Col. 1
    l                              % Col. 2
    l                              % Col. 3
    L{\widthof{Classification}}    % Col. 4
    L{\widthof{BiLSTM}}            % Col. 5
    L{\widthof{Feature}}           % Col. 6
    C{\widthof{Mod.}}              % Col. 7
    Y                              % Col. 8
    L{\widthof{Twitter Dataset 1}} % Col. 9
    L{\widthof{23,452 video}}        % Col. 10
    L{\widthof{4 (happiness, sad- }} % Col. 11
    L{\widthof{persuasiveness}}      % Col. 12
    L{\widthof{CMU-MOSEI (Acc2):}}   % Col. 13
    @{}}

%% Headers and footers:

\caption{Put caption here} \\
\toprule
\# & Ref. & Year & Model & Frameworks &
Fusion & Mod. & Features & Dataset & Samples &
No.\ of Classes & Task & Performance \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{13}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule
\# & Ref. & Year & Model & Frameworks &
Fusion & Mod. & Features & Dataset & Samples &
No.\ of Classes & Task & Performance \\
\midrule
\endhead

\addlinespace
\multicolumn{13}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


%% Body of table

% Entry 1
1 & \cite{PARK2016} & 2016 & 
Sentiment Classification \& Regression &
SVM \newline SVR & Feature Fusion & \TVA &
T: Unigrams, Bigrams \newline
V: Emotions, FAV, Eye Gaze, Movement Displacements \newline
A: MFCC, Pitch, VA (velocity) &
Persuasive Opinion Multimedia (POM) & 
1,000 movie reviews & 
2 (positive, negative) & 
Prediction of persuasiveness in movie reviews &
Acc: 70.34\% \newline 
PCC/Or: 0.34 \\*
\midrule

% Entry 2
2 & \cite{} & 2015 & 
Multi CNN & CNN & Feature Fusion & \TV &
T: Word vectors \newline V: Images &
Twitter Dataset 1 (TD1) \newline 
Twitter Dataset 2 (TD2) &
603 tweets \newline 1,369 tweets &
2 (positive, negative) &
Multimodal Sentiment Analysis &
TD1 (Acc): 78\% \newline 
TD2 (Acc): 79.6\% \\*
\midrule

% Entry 3
3 & \cite{} & 2020 & 
Multi-Attention Recurrent Neural Network (MA\nobreakdash-RNN) & 
BiGRU & Feature Fusion & \TVA &
T: Word2vec vectors \newline
V: feature maps, \# of channels, \# of frames, frame height $\times$ width \newline
A: MFCC, pitch, voice intensity, statistics, e.g.,~$\bar{x}$ &
CMU-MOSI & 2,199 video segments & 
2 (positive, negative) &
Multimodal Sentiment Analysis & 
Acc: 84.31\% \\*
\midrule

% Entry 4
4 & \cite{} & 2021 & 
Contextual Multimodal Fusion with Attention Model & 
BiLSTM & 
Feature Fusion, \newline 
Hier\-archical Fusion & \TVA &
T: Word vectors \newline
V: 3D-CNN features \newline
A: MFCC, pitch, voice intensity, statistics, e.g.,~$\bar{x}$ &
IEMOCAP \newline CMU-MOSI & 
5,498 utterances \newline 
2,199 video segments &
4 (happiness, sadness, anger, neutral) \newline 
2 (positive, negative) &
Multimodal Sentiment Analysis & 
IEMOCAP (Acc): 80.38\% \newline 
CMU-MOSI (Acc): 80.18\% \\*
\midrule

% Entry 5
5 & \cite{} & 2024 & 
Text-Centric Multimodal Contrastive Learning (TCMCL) & 
Siamese NN & 
Feature Fusion & \TVA &
T: BERT embeddings \newline
V: FACET library \newline
A: COVAREP toolkit &
CMU-MOSI \newline CMU-MOSEI & 
2,199 video segments \newline 
23,452 video segments &
7 (strongly positive to strongly negative) \newline 
7 (strongly positive to strongly negative) &
Multimodal Sentiment Analysis & 
CMU-MOSI (Acc2): 86.7\% \newline 
CMU-MOSEI (Acc2): 85.8\% \\*
% \midrule % not needed for very last entry

\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}


Addendum: The OP's 5 sample entries all fit on a single page. If one comments out the instruction \vspace*{3in} that occurs right before \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}..., one can simulate what partials tables on two pages will look like. Note, in particular, the continuation lines at the bottom right of the left-hand image and at the top-left of the right-hand image -- they are produced by the \endfoot and \endhead directives, respectively. If you're familiar with longtable syntax, you'll understand the purpose of these instructions immediately.


Hey this actually looks really good. I really appreciate your suggestion. I am going to try to add the other 55 columns and I will post back on here with an update. Once again, thank you.

@ririto - 55 entries rather than columns?

yes... lol I apologize I have been at this all day. 55 entries about 30 more to go

@ririto - Thanks for the "accept". :-) I've gone ahead and posted an addendum to illustrate how the xltabular machinery can accommodate page breaks automatically, very similarly to what longtable does.

I would rather use longtblr of tabularray package. Using it a code is a bit shorter (what is paid with a bit longer compilation time). Beside this for writing quantities I would employ siunitx package and for contents in seventh column (Features) use itemize list as provided by enumitem package.
Edit
In MWE below is now complete code as you provide in your question (added are rows 3 and 4). Since in all rows are lists, it is sensible to define their lists style for complete table and by this is a bit shortened table body code.
By comparison suggested solution with your MWE you can observe, that in suggested code is not used \makecell instructions anymore. They are replaced (where needed) by {<first line> \\ <second line>} which is tabularray package specific features.
Since in each rows are list, it is sensible to define their style once for whole table, immediately after begin{landscaape}
\documentclass[10pt,american]{report}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{tabularray}     % new
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,   % loaded as library, not used  in this MWE      
                siunitx,    % loaded as library
                varwidth}   % for lists in tables
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep, leftmargin=1.6em}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Caption text},
  label = {longtab:1}
                ]{hlines,
             colsep = 3pt,
             colspec = {c           % Column 1
                        c           % Column 2
                        c           % Column 3
                        Q[c, wd=18mm]  % Column 4
                        Q[l, wd=3em]   % Column 5
                        Q[l, wd=11mm]  % Column 6
                        c           % Column 7
                        X[1.5, l]   % Column 8
                        X[l]        % Column 9
                        Q[l, wd=4em]    % Column 10
                        X[l]        % Column 11
                        X[l]        % Column 12
                        X[l]        % Column 13
                        },
             rows = {m, font=\footnotesize},
             stretch = -1,
             measure = vbox,
             rowhead = 1}
% Header row
\# &        % Column 1
Ref. &      % Column 2
Year &      % Column 3
Model &     % Column 4
Frame\-works &% Column 5
Fusion &    % Column 6
Mod. &      % Column 7
Features &  % Column 8
Dataset &   % Column 9
Samples &   % Column 10
No. of Classes & % Column 11
Task &      % Column 12
Perfor\-mance \\ % Column 13
% table body
% Entry 1
1   & \cite{PARK2016}   & 2016 
    & Sentiment Classification \& Regression 
                        & {SVM \\ SVR}      
    & Feature Fusion    & {T \\ V \\ A}      
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item[T:]   Unigrams, Bigrams 
    \item[V:]   Emotions, FAV, Eye Gaze, Movement Displacements 
    \item[A:]   MFCC, Pitch, VA (velocity)
        \end{itemize}
                        & Persuasive Opinion Multimedia (POM) 
    & 1,000 movie reviews 
                        & 2 (positive, negative) 
    & Prediction of persuasiveness in movie reviews 
                        & {Acc: \qty{70.34}{\%} \\ PCC/Or: 0.34} \\
% Entry 2
2   & \cite{}           & 2015 
    & Multi CNN         & CNN 
    & Feature Fusion    & {T \\ V} 
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item[T:]   Unigrams, Bigrams
    \item[V:]   Emotions, FAV, Eye Gaze, Movement Displacements
        \end{itemize}
                & Twitter Dataset 1 (TD1) Twitter Dataset 2 (TD2)
    & {603 tweets \\ 1,369 tweets} 
                & 2 (positive, negative)
    & Multimodal Sentiment Analysis 
                & {TD1 (Acc): \qty{78}{\%} \\ TD2 (Acc): \qty{79.6}{\%}} \\
% Entry 3
3   & \cite{}   & 2020 
    & Multi-Attention Recurrent Neural Network (MA-RNN) 
                & BiGRU 
    & Feature Fusion 
                & {T \\ V \\ A} 
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item[T:]   Word2vec vectors 
    \item[V:]   feature maps, \# of channels, \# of frames, frame height x width 
    \item[A:]   MFCC, pitch, voice intensity, statistics e.g. $\bar{x}$
        \end{itemize}
                & CMU-MOSI 
    & 2,199 video segments 
                & 2 (positive,\allowbreak{} negative) 
    & Multimodal Sentiment Analysis 
                & Acc: \qty{84.31}{\%}          \\
% Entry 4
4   & \cite{}   & 2021 
    & Contextual Multimodal Fusion with Attention Model 
                & BiLSTM 
    & Feature Fusion Hierarchical Fusion
                & {T \\ V \\ A} 
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item[T:]   Word vectors 
    \item[V:]   3D-CNN features 
    \item[A:]   MFCC, pitch, voice intensity, statistics e.g. $\bar{x}$
        \end{itemize}
                & {IEMOCAP \\ CMU-MOSI} 
    & 5,498 utterances 2,199 video segments
                & 4 (happiness, sadness, anger, neutral) 
                  2 (positive, negative)
    & Multimodal Sentiment Analysis 
                & IEMOCAP (Acc): \qty{80.38}{\%} CMU-MOSI (Acc): \qty{80.18}{\%} \\
% Entry 5
5   & \cite{}   & 2024 
    & Text-Centric Multimodal Contrastive Learning (TCMCL) 
                & Siamese NN & Feature Fusion 
    & {T \\ V \\ A} 
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item[T:]   BERT embeddings 
    \item[V:]   FACET library  
    \item[A:]   COVAREP toolkit
        \end{itemize}
                & {CMU-MOSI \\ CMU-MOSEI} 
    & {2,199 video segments \\ 23,452 video segments} 
                & {7 (strongly positive to strongly negative)\\
                   7 (strongly positive to strongly negative)} 
    & Multimodal Sentiment Analysis 
                & {CMU-MOSI (Acc2): \qty{86.7}{\%} \\ CMU-MOSEI (Acc2): \qty{85.8}{\%}} \\
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}


Option rowhead in table preamble when table span several pages, carry about repeating caption marked with "(continue)" at each part of table (except first) and with "Continued on next page" at end of table parts (except at last).

I like the itemize for features, I will try this out
